# Resnick - Probability Path - Exercise 7.6

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, probability-limit-theorems

I'm trying to solve this exercise:

> Suppose ${X_k,k \ge 1}$ are independent randon variables and suppose $X_k$ has a gamma density $f_k(x)$,
>
> $f_k(x)=\frac{x^{\gamma_k-1}\rm{e}^{-x}}{\Gamma(\gamma_k)}, x>0, \gamma_k>0$.
>
> Give necessary and sufficient conditions for $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{X_k}} $. to converge almost
>   surely. (Compare with the treatment of sums of exponentially distributed
>   random variables).

I know $X_k \sim Gama(\gamma_k,1)$, then $E(X_k)=V(X_k)=\gamma_k$.

So, by the theorem of Kolmogorov Convergence Criterion, we have:
If $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{V(X_k)}}< \infty $, then
$\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {[{X_k}-E(X_k)]}$ converges almost surely.

Let $M$ such that $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {[{X_k}-\gamma_k]} \to M $ converges almost surely.

Thus, for $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\gamma_k}<\infty $   $\Rightarrow $
 $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {X_k}\rightarrow M+\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\gamma_k}<\infty $ a.s.

Therefore, can I say that is sufficient and necessary that $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\gamma_k}<\infty$?

Or do I need to show the other side, like

if $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {{X_k}}$ converge a.s., then $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\gamma_k}<\infty$?

Comment: *"Or do I need to show the other side"* - can you find a counterexample?

Comment: do you mean, just show that if $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty {X_k}$ diverges/(do not converges a.s.) then $\sum\nolimits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\gamma_k}$ diverges too?

Comment: Hint: by Kolmogorov's 3 series test, if $\sum_n X_n$ converges, then $\sum_n P(X_n>1)<\infty$. But as $\gamma\to 0$, $P(\Gamma(\gamma, 1)>1)\sim K\gamma$, which yields the required convergence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other side can be proved as follows:

Assume that $\sum_n X_n$ converges a.s.,

So, by Kolmogorov's 3 series we have that:

(i)$\sum_n P(|X_n|>c)<\infty \Rightarrow P(|X_n|>c)\rightarrow0$,

which means $X_n$ is bounded, i.e. $\exists$c such that $|X_n|<c, \forall n\in \mathbb{N}$. Be $c_0$ such value, thus:

(ii) $\sum_n Var(X_n 1_{[|X_n|\leq c_0]}) = \sum_n Var(X_n) = \sum_n \gamma_n <\infty$

(iii) $\sum_n E(X_n 1_{[|X_n|\leq c_0]}) = \sum_n E(X_n) = \sum_n \gamma_n <\infty$

$\Rightarrow \sum_n \gamma_n <\infty$